# Couldn't execute 'show create table `xxx.yyy`': Table 'yyy' doesn't exist in engine (1932) al actualizar libc6

Tags: sql, mariadb

**Buenas,** he tenido que volver a rehacer mi server (Debian 9) en Proxmox. Le actualicé un paquete (libc6) y rompí las dependencias (no le hice un snapshot, se me olvidó...). Entre una de ellas la de MySQL / MariaDB, no pude tampoco hacer una backup desde PhpMyAdmin porque el daemon tampoco funciona y no me podía conectar a la base de datos.

Ahora he instalado Debian 10, pero tengo problemas al recuperar la base de datos de la otra máquina. Me tira el siguiente error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `xxx.yyy`': Table 'yyy' doesn't exist in engine (1932)
```

He estado buscando, he intentado reparar la base de datos con ayuda de las siguientes preguntas:

```
root@debian:~# mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > all_databases.sql
Enter password:
mysqldump: Got error: 1932: "Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine" when using LOCK TABLES
root@debian:~# mysqldump --skip-lock-tables -u root -p --all-databases > all_databases.sql
Enter password:
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `gtid_slave_pos`': Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine (1932)
```

**Source:** https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213931725-Dump-of-the-MySQL-database-hosted-on-the-Plesk-server-fails-mysqldump-table-doesn-t-exist-when-using-LOCK-TABLES

```
root@debian:~# mysqlfrm --server=xxx:yyy@localhost:3306 test.frm --port=3310
WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
# Source on localhost: ...
Usage: mysqlfrm --server=[user[:<pass>]@host[:<port>][:<socket>]|<login-path>[:<port>][:<socket>]] [path\tbl1.frm|db:tbl.frm]

mysqlfrm: error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

**Source:** https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127813

```
MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER TABLE mysql.gtid_slave_pos DISCARD TABLESPACE;
ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine
```

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997127/restore-mysql-database-using-only-frm-and-ibd-files

Alguien me echa una mano?